Syntax Error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'styles')
I'm trying to build library with following command but get error "Syntax Error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'styles')":
$ vue-cli-service build --target lib --name login mod/login/Component/page.vue

Response:
⠴  Building for production as library (commonjs,umd,umd-min)...

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error                                                                                                                                                                     11:07:40 AM

 error  in ./mod/login/Component/page.vue

Syntax Error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'styles')

package.json, stripped
{
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.12.16",
        "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.16",
        "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.10",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
        "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
        "eslint": "^7.32.0",
        "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.7.1",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.4.10"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "axios": "^1.7.7",
        "core-js": "^3.8.3",
        "toastr": "^2.1.4",
        "vue": "^3.2.13", // installed 3.5
        "vue-i18n": "^10.0.4",
        "vue-router": "^4.4.5"
        // derived dependencies
        // webpack@5.95.0
        // vue-loader@17.4.2
    },
...
}

page.vue:
<script>
import {defineComponent} from "vue";

export default defineComponent((vars) => {
  return {
    displayName: 'Login',
    components: {
    },
    data() {
      return {
      };
    }
  };
});
</script>

<template>
  <main>
    ...
  </main>
</template>

I have tried to add to package.json resolutions to vue-loader 15, 16, 17 but no luck.

vue-cli being in maintenance mode, maybe try the recommended migration to vite which doesn't use any vue-loader.  here also is documentation for library mode if needed

Found the problem. Logical, although not too easy to spot.
The command I ran was:
$ vue-cli-service build --target lib --name login mod/login/Component/page.vue

...which used globally installed vue-cli-service (as instructed here https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html) which was different version than the one in the package.json, and which in turn had installed its own version of webpack, etc, etc.
I should have ran:
$ yarn build --target lib --name login mod/login/Component/page.vue

Excerpt from package.json:
"scripts": {
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
},

Uninstalled global vue-cli-service to avoid future confusions.
Hope this saves the time for somebody.
